# mail send with php but in headers shows a character

Tags: php

My requirement is mail send using php.But header of mail shows a special character.
Mail header section in gmail is

```
from:    zamisoftt&lt
reply-to:    zamisoftt&lt,
hr@vestroxinc.com&gt
```

My header section in PHP is

```
 $header_mail="select content from mail_header where mail_type='payment'";
$header_mail2=mysql_query($header_mail);
$fet=mysql_fetch_array($header_mail2);
$content=htmlentities($fet['content']);

$Headers = "From:".$content."\r\n" . 
"Reply-To:".$content."\r\n" . 
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; 
$Headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$Headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()."\r\n";
```

With out the htmlentities function mail go to sapm.Now mail go to inbox with these special charecter in header in mail.Any body give any solution for these issue?

Comment: BTW, you should stop using mysql_* functions. They are deprecated and will soon be gone from modern PHP versions; Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `htmlentities` to set `$contentent`, so obviously you're getting some characters there escaped as HTML entities. `htmlentities` is not useful for mail headers.

Maybe it is going to spam for a whole different reason, like bad or missing SPF, ill-configured STMP server etc.

Comment: with out htmlentities ,mail go to spam.